# ThreeJS - Additional parameter to ColladaLoader callback

Tags: three.js

I use the `ColladaLoader` from ThreeJS like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load(file, this.onModelLoadingCompleted);

private onModelLoadingCompleted(collada) {
    scene.add(collada.scene);
}
```

I want now to add a custom function parameter to the `onModelLoadingCompleted` function. Is this possible? If so, how to do it?

In particular I am looking for something like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.load(file, this.onModelLoadingCompleted(collada, customProperty));

private onModelLoadingCompleted(collada, customProperty) {
    scene.add(collada.scene);
    //do something with customProperty
}
```

Comment: What do you want this custom property to contain? Is its value known before you request the model, or is it some content of the COLLADA file that would need to be parsed by `ColladaLoader`?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Yes it is a value known before. In particular I want to use the file URL (in the example vefore the `file` parameter) in `onModelLoadingCompleted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous callback with access to the extra variable. Example:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var customProperty = 3.14159;
loader.load( file, function (collada) {
  this.onModelLoadingCompleted(collada, customProperty);
}.bind(this) );


// elsewhere:
onModelLoadingCompleted(collada, customProperty) {
    scene.add(collada.scene);
    //do something with customProperty
}
```